# Laravel Blade: What is best practice for adding javascript in blade files?

Tags: laravel, laravel-blade

I inherited a Laravel project that has many blade files with javascript inside  tags within the blade file.  The issue is that there is a lot of repetitive JS logic so I'd like to extract the JS and create JS files to include in the blade? Example: `<script src="{{ asset('js/components/file.js')}}"></script>` 
 Is this the best practice for blade files or is it expected to be have the JS within the actual file?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

First you have to assign where yo want to push scripts in your layout. for example, say `layout.blade.php` is your main layout file and you want to inject codes after footer. So add

```
@stack('scripts')
```

after footer.

Now in your blade file, use `@push` to inject your code.

```
@push('scripts')
<script>
// your code
</script>
@endpush
```

check [blade stack](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/blade#stacks) for further detail.

Answer (score 3):

if you use `webpack.mix.js` :

```js
    mix.js('resources/js/app.js', 'public/js')
       .js('resources/js/my-super-amazing-script.js', 'public/js')
```

And in your main `my-layout.blade.php` :

```html
    ...
        @yield('javascript')
    </body>
```

Then, in your specific page :

```html
    @extend('my-layout.blade.php')
    ...
    @once
    @push('javascript')
        <script src="{{ mix('js/my-super-amazing-script.js') }}" defer></script>
    @endpush
    @endonce
```

Answer (score 2):

I recommend you to maintain a specific section for page-specific javascript.

Please refer the following examples..

Example template.blade.php

```
  <body>

    @yield('content')

    @include('_partial.scripts')

    @yield('page-script')

    @include('_partial.footer')

</body>
```

then

```
@section('page-script')
<script type="text/javascript">
    // your custom script
</script>
@stop
```